# how to find an actual number for E(X) with the given information?

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Let $X$ be a positive continuous random variable with the probability density function $f_X(t)$. Suppose that there is a random variable $Y$, for which the pdf is $f_Y(t) = t\,f_X(t)$ (for all real numbers $t$). What is $E(X)$ (find an actual number)? Express $\operatorname{var}(X)$ in terms of $E(Y)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please make sure to include what steps you have taken towards solving the problem and where you have gotten stuck, so we know what hints to provide you.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f_Y(t)$ is a pdf, $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_Y(t)\ dt = 1$. Since $f_Y(t) = tf_X(t)$, then $\displaystyle E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty tf_X(t)\ dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_Y(t)\ dt = 1$.

For the second part, use the fact that $\displaystyle E(Y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty t^2f_X(t)\ dt = E(X^2)$ to help you write the variance of $X$ in terms of $E(Y)$.

Comment: So then var(X)=e(Y)-1?

Comment: That's correct.